# Construct and initialise armadillo vector and matrix

Tags: c++, class, constructor, armadillo

I am trying to understand how to initialise an armadillo vector and matrix in a class. The code I have written so far is:

```
class EcosystemCarbonStateType{

private:
    arma::vec B;
    arma::mat K;

public:
    EcosystemCarbonStateType() : B(2), K(2,2)
    {
        B.fill(1);
        K.fill(2.0);
    }

    void init();
};
```

after having instantiated the class, I try to run the `init` method, however strange results are produced.
Init looks like this

```
void EcosystemCarbonStateType::init(){

    B(0) = 0.45;
    B(1) = 0.55;

    K(0, 0) = 0.00176;
    K(1, 1) = 0.000100104;
 }
```

If I then print `B` and `K` B seems to be ok while `K` is empty. Am I doing something wrong with the constructor?

Comment: Armadillo uses 0 based indexing, like the rest of C++. The top-left element in matrix K is K(0,0).

Comment: Sorry, the indexes were wrong but in the code they were correct, so the problem persists. I edited the question

Comment: Perhaps change the size of vectors and matrices in the init() function, not in the constructor. Example: `B.set_size(2);` or `B.zeros(2);`, `K.set_size(2,2)` or `K.zeros(2,2);`